# Get ArrayList element but only returning the elements address

Tags: java, arraylist, return

Hi I am trying to get elements from an ArrayList in one class from another class. So I am pulling data from a mysql database and then storing it in an Arraylist. I want to access the data from that ArrayList and print them out from another class but for some reason its only printing the address of the element not the actual element itself.

It is of type Team which has three elements in the constructor a String and two ints.

Getting it from the DB:

```
while(res.next()){
            teamList.add(new Team(res.getString("Team_Name"), res.getInt("Goal_Difference"),
                    res.getInt("Points")));
        }
```

Return statement for the ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<Team> getTeamList(){
    return teamList;
}
```

and where I am trying to print it:

```
public Verdict(){
    ArrayList<Team> leagueList = new LeagueSQLConnector().teamList;
    System.out.println(leagueList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to ovveride the `toString()` method in your `Team` class.

Something looks like below.

```
class Team{
    private String name;
    private String type;

    //constructor

    //setters

    //getters


    @Override
            public String toString() {
                 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                 result.append(this.name ).append(",");  
                 result.append(this.type );
                 return result.toString();
            }
}
```

As per docs of `toString`()

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

Comment: They're printing out an `ArrayList<Team>`, not just a `Team`, so implementing `.toString()` alone won't solve the issue - they'll also need to iterate over that collection, printing out each instance of `Team` individually.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The [AbstractCollection toString method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29), inherited by ArrayList, does iterate over all the elements, using each element's own toString method to get its string representation.

Comment: As Patricia said, Just printing the list alone enough. No need to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get your output nice and pretty is that compiler does not "know" how your object should be converted to `String`. What you see is result of [default `toString` implementation for `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). You should implement `toString` method, which will be called whenever the `Team` object will be "converted" to string.
There are a couple common ways to achieve this:

**[Apache commons-lang](https://github.com/google/guava):**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

This is a simple one-liner that will grab all class attributes and print them.

**[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this.getClass())
        .add("Team name", name)
        .add("Goal difference", goalDifference)
        .add("Points", points)
        .toString();
}
```

This one is good if you want to control which attributes should be displayed.

**The most straightforward way:**

Write `toString` method by hand (IDEs like Intellij Idea provide handy code generation for this). You don't need any libraries for this.

Then you are free to do`System.out.println(leagueList)` as `List` has a nice [implementation of `toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()).